# How can I pull a value from last clicked div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a boggle game in Js and I want to add some features to make life more simpler. And not having to duplicate my code a thousand times. Basically I have a function called addLetter() which simply pushes the letter clicked on to an array. It only works for one letter right now and I dont want to hardcode it. So how can I pull the value from the clicked div? I dont want to make 16 functions to push one letter from a single div.

Source code:

```
var letters = [];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var dice1 = ['R', 'I', 'F', 'O', 'B', 'X'];
var dice2 = ['I', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'E', 'Y'];
var dice3 = ['D', 'E', 'N', 'O', 'W', 'S'];
var dice4 = ['U', 'T', 'O', 'K', 'N', 'D'];
var dice5 = ['H', 'M', 'S', 'R', 'A', 'O'];
var dice6 = ['L', 'U', 'P', 'E', 'T', 'S'];
var dice7 = ['A', 'C', 'I', 'T', 'O', 'A'];
var dice8 = ['Y', 'L', 'G', 'K', 'U', 'E'];
var dice9 = ['Q', 'B', 'M', 'J', 'O', 'A'];
var dice10 = ['E', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'N'];
var dice11 = ['V', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'G', 'N'];
var dice12 = ['B', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'Y', 'T'];
var dice13 = ['E', 'Z', 'A', 'V', 'N', 'D'];
var dice14 = ['R', 'A', 'L', 'E', 'S', 'C'];
var dice15 = ['U', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'R', 'G'];
var dice16 = ['U', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'R', 'G'];

var dice1rnd = (dice1[random]);
var dice2rnd = (dice2[random]);
var dice3rnd = (dice3[random]);
var dice4rnd = (dice4[random]);
var dice5rnd = (dice5[random]);
var dice6rnd = (dice6[random]);
var dice7rnd = (dice7[random]);
var dice8rnd = (dice8[random]);
var dice9rnd = (dice9[random]);
var dice10rnd = (dice10[random]);
var dice11rnd = (dice11[random]);
var dice12rnd = (dice12[random]);
var dice13rnd = (dice13[random]);
var dice14rnd = (dice14[random]);
var dice15rnd = (dice15[random]);
var dice16rnd = (dice16[random]);

console.log(dice1[random]);
console.log(dice2[random]);
console.log(dice3[random]);
console.log(dice4[random]);
console.log(dice5[random]);
console.log(dice6[random]);
console.log(dice7[random]);
console.log(dice8[random]);
console.log(dice9[random]);
console.log(dice10[random]);
console.log(dice11[random]);
console.log(dice12[random]);
console.log(dice13[random]);
console.log(dice14[random]);
console.log(dice15[random]);
console.log(dice16[random]);
console.log(letters);

document.getElementById('dice1rnd').innerHTML = dice1rnd;
document.getElementById('dice1rnd').addEventListener("click", addLetter, false);
document.getElementById('dice2rnd').innerHTML = dice2rnd;
document.getElementById('dice3rnd').innerHTML = dice3rnd;
document.getElementById('dice4rnd').innerHTML = dice4rnd;
document.getElementById('dice5rnd').innerHTML = dice5rnd;
document.getElementById('dice6rnd').innerHTML = dice6rnd;
document.getElementById('dice7rnd').innerHTML = dice7rnd;
document.getElementById('dice8rnd').innerHTML = dice8rnd;
document.getElementById('dice9rnd').innerHTML = dice9rnd;
document.getElementById('dice10rnd').innerHTML = dice10rnd;
document.getElementById('dice11rnd').innerHTML = dice11rnd;
document.getElementById('dice12rnd').innerHTML = dice12rnd;
document.getElementById('dice13rnd').innerHTML = dice13rnd;
document.getElementById('dice14rnd').innerHTML = dice14rnd;
document.getElementById('dice15rnd').innerHTML = dice15rnd;
document.getElementById('dice16rnd').innerHTML = dice16rnd;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = letters;

function addLetter() {
    letters.push(dice1rnd);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = letters;
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a read/write property, just read the value from the clicked div (event.target) and create the random index in the `addLetter` function. And if all the dices are random, you could create them dynamically in a loop, and put the values in a nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

You don't need nearly so many variables — use arrays, `map`, and `forEach` loops instead.

Also, your `random` only gets calculated once, so it will always be the same. If you put it in a function (`() => ...`) it becomes callable (`random()`) so you can generate many different values.

```js
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

const dice = [
     ['R', 'I', 'F', 'O', 'B', 'X'],
     ['I', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'E', 'Y'],
     ['D', 'E', 'N', 'O', 'W', 'S'],
     ['U', 'T', 'O', 'K', 'N', 'D'],
     ['H', 'M', 'S', 'R', 'A', 'O'],
     ['L', 'U', 'P', 'E', 'T', 'S'],
     ['A', 'C', 'I', 'T', 'O', 'A'],
     ['Y', 'L', 'G', 'K', 'U', 'E'],
     ['Q', 'B', 'M', 'J', 'O', 'A'],
     ['E', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'N'],
     ['V', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'G', 'N'],
     ['B', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'Y', 'T'],
     ['E', 'Z', 'A', 'V', 'N', 'D'],
     ['R', 'A', 'L', 'E', 'S', 'C'],
     ['U', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'R', 'G'],
     ['U', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'R', 'G'],
]

const randomize = () => {
    const results = dice.map(die => die[random()])

    document.querySelectorAll('.result').forEach((el, idx) => {
        el.textContent = results[idx]
    })
}

randomize()

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', randomize)
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.result {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> <div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div><div class="result"></div></div>


<button id="btn">Randomize</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly address your concern, you can use `target` prop of the event that is passed to your method to make it dynamic.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

example:

```js
function addLetter (event) {
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML) // => should print contents of clicked div.
}
```